# create js movieclip object containing an mp4 video in a tween does not work with gotoAndPlay calls

Tags: createjs, easeljs, movieclip, timeline, tween

I have some code that used CreateJS /EaselJS to create a MovieClip that contains a Tween that contains an mp4 video.  In MovieClip there is a method called 'gotoAndPlay' that you can use to change the timeline position of the playhead to a certain frame number.  When using this method to change the play position of the video the tweens work but not the Tween that contains the mp4 movie...this object does not load is result in a blank video tag on the page except for the first play through of the clip.  Once the mp4 video has been played it didn't play again if the position was set to it through gotoAndPlay...any ideas on how to fix this or if something wrong might be happening?

Comment: It appears that the adobe animate html5 video component is not updating the video tag when gotoAndPlay is used, not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In ActionScript animations, FLV movies can be locked to the timeline.  But in HTML Canvas animations, MP4 movies are not really fully-fledged "Animate" objects. They look the same for the most part but the integration is not as tight as in Flash.

Since the videos exist outside of the Canvas, you'll need to use jQuery or JavaScript to address them. This can be done by using the Code Snippets  in the HTML5 Canvas - Components - Video folder.

As an advance warning, "seeking" to different locations in an MP4 video the way you described is not as reliable as it was in Flash.  Browsers like Internet Explorer don't handle seeking well and will likely crash.  If frame -by-frame accuracy is important, you may find the best visual results by avoiding the video component and converting your movie to an actual MovieClip in Animate CC, which will increase your file size significantly.